# Always use Firefox for web-apps

Tags: firefox, 12.10, webapps

I am using Google Chrome (not Chromium, I have my reasons) as default web browser, but I want to use Firefox for Ubuntu web apps.

Is there any way to force web apps to open in Firefox and not in default web browser?

Comment: This is already filed as a bug. Check out https://bugs.launchpad.net/libunity-webapps/+bug/1036726

Comment: I don't understand why this question was considered off topic and closed. Double-checked the FAQ.

Comment: @Alex7Kom - confirmed bugs are off-topic.  Please subscribe to the bug-report for further updates.

Comment: @fossfreedom Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/):

To set your default desktop applications for actions such as Web Browser, Email, or Video, open the System Settings window from the panel.

[image]

Select the Details icon in the System Settings window.

[image]

Select the Default Applications category and use the drop-down boxes to select a default application. Application will appear here after you’ve installed them – for example, you can install VLC and select it as your default video player from here.

[image]